# Different types shown when iterating over a String's UTF8View

Tags: swift, string, unicode, utf-8

I'm currently studying string in swift. I have two version of the same code

[image]

[image]

The variable in the for in loop are suppose to have the same type, but as you can see, the type is actually different?

I must be missing something here, but can't seem to figure out.

Comment: This is merely a presentation thing – they're both of type `UTF8.CodeUnit` aka. `UInt8`. Looks like it's fixed in Xcode 8.3 beta.

Comment: @Hamish Could you expand on "its fixed in xcode 8,3 beta" a little bit? So it is a bug in xcode?

Comment: There's a lot of type aliases in Swift. `UTF8.CodeUnit` is basically the same as `String.UTF8View._Element` (`String.UTF8View` is the collection of `CodeUnit`s and `_Element` is a specific element in the collection, i.e. a `CodeUnit`). It's not surprising Xcode will pick different type aliases when doing type inference depending on how a variable is declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a presentation thing – the `_IndexableBase` protocol (which `Collection` [internally derives from](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L637)) declares an [`_Element` associated type](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift#L61) as a workaround for a conformance cycle:

```
protocol _IndexableBase {

      // ...

      // The declaration of _Element and subscript here is a trick used to
      // break a cyclic conformance/deduction that Swift can't handle.  We
      // need something other than a Collection.Iterator.Element that can
      // be used as IndexingIterator<T>'s Element.  Here we arrange for
      // the Collection itself to have an Element type that's deducible from
      // its subscript.  Ideally we'd like to constrain this Element to be the same
      // as Collection.Iterator.Element (see below), but we have no way of
      // expressing it today.
      associatedtype _Element

      // ...
      subscript(position: Index) -> _Element { get }
      // ...
}
```

*(Note this will all change once [recursive protocol constraints](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0157-recursive-protocol-constraints.md) are implemented)*

In practice, this associated type should always be satisfied by the same type as the `Collection`'s `Iterator.Element`, due to the fact that `Collection` has a

```
subscript(position: Index) -> Iterator.Element { get }
```

requirement. Thus when conforming to `Collection`, the compiler will by default deduce that `Iterator.Element` == `_Element`.

With [`String.UTF8View`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.utf8view), it implements `Collection` with an `Iterator.Element` of type [`UTF8.CodeUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/utf8/codeunit) (aka. `UInt8`). Therefore the types `String.UTF8View._Element`, `String.UTF8View.Iterator.Element`, `UTF8.CodeUnit` and `UInt8` are all the same.

You can easily verify this for yourself by comparing the metatype values:

```
print(UInt8.self == UTF8.CodeUnit.self)                    // true
print(UInt8.self == String.UTF8View._Element.self)         // true
print(UInt8.self == String.UTF8View.Iterator.Element.self) // true
```

Xcode simply chooses to *display* different type aliases in this case. Although  in Xcode 8.3 beta 4, they are both displayed as `UTF8.CodeUnit`.

Comment: Funny that the documentation for [String.UTF8View](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/String.UTF8View/) is the one explaining the exact example in the question but that Xcode 8.3 chooses to show `UTF8.CodeUnit` which is hardly [documented](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/UTF8/) at all.